# TypeConverter unavailable in Maui?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

So I was trying to create a TypeConverter in Maui. And apparently, the methods aren't virtual anymore. How do I convert this Xamarin Forms code to Maui?

Also `TypeConversion` seems to be missing altogether, Tried to find any MS documentation on this, Well nothing there either, I am going through their Github right now for clues as to what's the right way to do this now with Maui, But for the time being, I am adding this here so someone who has a clue could guide me too,

```
[TypeConversion(typeof(BaseAnimation))]
public class BaseAnimationTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromInvariantString(string value)
    {
        var type = (AnimationTypes)Enum.Parse(typeof(AnimationTypes), value);
        return new DefaultAnimationExtension() { Source = type }.ProvideValue(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not 100% sure what it was for Xamarin, we might have had our own type because of reasons. But for .NET MAUI we're using the `TypeConverter` class that is in the .NET framework. So the one that's in `System.ComponentModel`.

If you add `using System.ComponentModel;` in the top of your class here it should work.

You can see a working example in the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit MediaElement here: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.MediaElement/MediaSource/MediaSource.shared.cs#L9

Answer (score -1):

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            EffectsView effectsView = (EffectsView)parameter;
            return effectsView.ScaleFactor == 1;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Value converters have nothing to do with the type converters mentioned in the question.